# Retrieve SQS Messages-available/Message-in-flight using Node.js Aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-nodejs

I need to get the number of SQS messages available and messages in flight using aws-sdk with javascript.
Can someone please give me some kind of reference or code snippet?
I need metadata for this SQS. I can send Messages and read it but need this info to conclude if there is high load on my infrastructure

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [GetQueueAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#getQueueAttributes-property). As per your requirements, fetching only `ApproximateNumberOfMessages`, `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible`, `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed` should suffice. You can read more about these parameters [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueAttributes.html).

Sample code to get you moving:

```js
var params = {
  QueueUrl: '<sqs_queue>',
  AttributeNames: [
    ApproximateNumberOfMessages,
    ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible,
    ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed
  ]
};
sqs.getQueueAttributes(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
  else     console.log(data);
});
```